# Sand 3D Printer Slicing Issue

Tags: interface, arrays, indexing

For my doctoral thesis I am building a 3D printer based loosely off of one from the University of Twente:

http://pwdr.github.io/

So far, everything has gone relatively smoothly. The hardware part took longer than expected, but the electronics frighten me a little bit. I can sucessfully jog all the motors and, mechanically, everything does what is supposed to do.

However, now that I am working on the software side, I am getting headaches.

The Pwder people wrote a code that uses Processing to take an .STL file and slice it into layers. Upon running the code, a Processing GUI opens where I can load a model. The model loads fine (I'm using the Utah Teapot) and shows that it will take 149 layers.

Upon hitting "convert" the program is supposed to take the .STL file and slice it into layers, followed by writing a text file that I can then upload to an SD card. The printer will then print directly from the SD card.

However, when I hit "convert" I get an "Array Index Out of Bounds" error. I'm not quite sure what this means.. can anyone enlighten me?

The code can be found below, along with a picture of the error.

Thank you.

[image]

```
    // Convert the graphical output of the sliced STL into a printable         binary format. 
    // The bytes are read by the Arduino firmware

    PrintWriter output, outputUpper;

    int loc;
    int LTR = 0;
    int lowernozzles = 8;
    int uppernozzles = 4;
    int nozzles = lowernozzles+uppernozzles;

    int printXcoordinate = 120+280;  // Left margin 120
    int printYcoordinate = 30+190;  // Top margin 30
    int printWidth = 120;        // Total image width 650
    int printHeight = 120;      // Total image height 480

    int layer_size = printWidth * printHeight/nozzles * 2;

    void convertModel() {

      // Create config file for the printer, trailing comma for convenience  
      output = createWriter("PWDR/PWDRCONF.TXT");        output.print(printWidth+","+printHeight/nozzles+","+maxSlices+","+inkSaturation+ ",");
      output.flush();
      output.close();

      int index = 0;
      byte[] print_data = new byte[layer_size * 2];

      // Steps of 12 nozzles in Y direction
      for (int y = printYcoordinate; y < printYcoordinate+printHeight;  y=y+nozzles ) {
        // Set a variable to know wheter we're moving LTR of RTL
        LTR++;  
        // Step in X direction  
        for (int x = 0; x < printWidth; x++) {

          // Clear the temp strings
          String[] LowerStr = {""};
          String LowerStr2 = "";
          String[] UpperStr = {""};
          String UpperStr2 = "";

          // For every step in Y direction, sample the 12 nozzles
          for ( int i=0; i<nozzles; i++) {
            // Calculate the location in the pixel array, use total window  width!
            // Use the LTR to determine the direction

            if (LTR % 2 == 1){
              loc = printXcoordinate + printWidth - x + (y+i) * width;
            } else {
              loc = printXcoordinate + x + (y+i) * width;
            }

            if (brightness(pixels[loc]) < 100) {

              // Write a zero when the pixel is white (or should be white, as the preview is inverted)
              if (i<uppernozzles) {
                UpperStr = append(UpperStr, "0");
              } else {
                LowerStr = append(LowerStr, "0");
              }
            } else {
              // Write a one when the pixel is black     
              if (i<uppernozzles) {
                UpperStr = append(UpperStr, "1");                  
              } else {
                LowerStr = append(LowerStr, "1");
              }
            }
          } 

          LowerStr2 = join(LowerStr, "");
          print_data[index] = byte(unbinary(LowerStr2));
          index++;

          UpperStr2 = join(UpperStr, "");
          print_data[index] = byte(unbinary(UpperStr2));
          index++;
        }
      }

      if (sliceNumber >= 1 && sliceNumber < 10){
        String DEST_FILE = "PWDR/PWDR000"+sliceNumber+".DAT";
        File dataFile = sketchFile(DEST_FILE);
        if (dataFile.exists()){
          dataFile.delete();
        }
        saveBytes(DEST_FILE, print_data); // Savebytes directly causes bug  under Windows
      } else if (sliceNumber >= 10 && sliceNumber < 100){
        String DEST_FILE = "PWDR/PWDR00"+sliceNumber+".DAT";
        File dataFile = sketchFile(DEST_FILE);
        if (dataFile.exists()){
          dataFile.delete();
        }
        saveBytes(DEST_FILE, print_data); // Savebytes directly causes bug   under Windows
      } else if (sliceNumber >= 100 && sliceNumber < 1000){
        String DEST_FILE = "PWDR/PWDR0"+sliceNumber+".DAT";
        File dataFile = sketchFile(DEST_FILE);
        if (dataFile.exists()){
          dataFile.delete();
        }
        saveBytes(DEST_FILE, print_data); // Savebytes directly causes bug  under Windows
      } else if (sliceNumber >= 1000) {
        String DEST_FILE = "PWDR/PWDR"+sliceNumber+".DAT";
        File dataFile = sketchFile(DEST_FILE);
        if (dataFile.exists()){
          dataFile.delete();
        }
        saveBytes(DEST_FILE, print_data); // Savebytes directly causes bug  under Windows
      }

      sliceNumber++;
      println(sliceNumber);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that print_data is smaller than index. (For example, if index is 123, but print_data only has 122 elements.)

Size of print_data is layer_size * 2 or printWidth * printHeight/nozzles * 4 or 4800

Max size of index is printHeight/nozzles * 2 * printWidth or 20*120 or 2400.

This seems alright, so I probably missed something, and it appears to be placing data in element 4800, which is weird. I suggest a bunch of print statements to get the size of print_data and the index.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I learned that's what it means, but I'm not sure how to fix it? My programming skills are abysmal, I'm more on the hardware side.

Comment: That's just it; I'm not sure what's wrong here. The actual code looks correct, and I don't see any way for the index to hit 4800. There could be something weird with the language, but the logic appears fine.